# Are these different server /etc/init.d/mysql server vs /opt/lampp/lampp mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Recently i installed Lampp on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.After that i  did these command bellow:

```
user@pc:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.15-1...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

i also did this command to start mysql individually:

```
user@pc:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start 
......
 * MySQL Community Server 5.6.25 is started
```

I am asking this because recently i got some problem on phpmyadmin login photo given below.
[image]

i did follow many online suggestions like editing `/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` .But nothing solved the problem.

However i when stop `/etc/init.d/mysql`, then phpmyadmin takes the login as:
**user: root pass: [nothing].it works fine**.

photo given below:
[image]

But to remove any existing mysql i already used this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server
```

So i want to know that  **are there 2 mysql server in my machine.If so then how i can remove the 2nd one [/etc/init.d/mysql]**.please let me know for further information.thanks.

Updates:
i 1st run the xampp & then /etc/init.d/mysql  start , got this output:

```
 $ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.15-1...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.

$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql  start
......
 * MySQL Community Server 5.6.25 did not start. Please check logs for more details.
```

after that experiment , i think they are same. am i correct.

Comment: MySQL typically installs some scripts in `/etc/init.d/`. So, just seeing that script is not enough to answer the question.

You could start the server in XAMP and check which files are opened (config, database, etc), or where the mysqld process is coming from.

The do the same by starting from `/etc/init.d`.

Comment: @ Richard St-Cyr thanks.i just add few updates to test what you suggested me.